# youtube zend api: Just results shorter than n minutes

Tags: php, zend-framework, search, youtube-api

I want my query to result only in videos, that are shorter than for example 7 minutes. Is that possible?

Currently I use this:

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setOrderBy('relevance');
$query->setSafeSearch('none');
$query->setVideoQuery($searchTerms);

// Note that we need to pass the version number to the query URL function
// to ensure backward compatibility with version 1 of the API.
$videoFeed = $yt->getVideoFeed($query->getQueryUrl(2));
```

The docs say, there is a "duration" parameter: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=de#durationsp

But unfortunately I had no luck with

```
$query->setDuration('short');
```

But that that would not do it anyway, while it look for videos shorter than four minutes.

Any ideas?

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might want to try `$query->setSeconds(240);`

I found the info : `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_Extension_Duration` and [Interacting with Gdata](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.introduction.html#zend.gdata.introduction.services)

Good Luck.

Comment: Sorry. Does not work. I helped myself using the javascript api and simply skipped the video if it a duration longer than x seconds.